# Chef - using powershell_script from within ruby_block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to use powershell_script from within a ruby_block?
I want to run the powershell script during the convergence phase and not the compilation phase. 
The current code doesn't work:

```
ruby_block 'ruby block so that code is run during convergence phase and not compilation phase' do
   block do
      buildNumber = "123"
      powershell_script 'run powershell script' do
      environment ({'buildNumber' => buildNumber})
      code "path/to/script/script.ps1"
      end
   end
action :run
end
```

I know you can use a guard on the powershell_script outside the ruby_block to make it run during convergence but I need the local variable buildNumber that is defined inside the ruby block.

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me:

```
x = Chef::Resource::PowershellScript.new('unzipper script',run_context)
    x.code 'D:/git/chef/cookbooks/java-8-upgrade/unzipper.ps1'
    x.environment ({'buildNumber' => buildNumber})
    x.run_action :run
```

Comment: Please don't use that, it really really won't work correctly in some cases (ex. ChefSpec tests).

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case, you can probably use the `powershell_out` helper method. For more complex cases, make a custom resource and use the normal resource. Do not use manual resource invocation (`Chef::Resource::Foo.new` as we explicitly do not support this and know for a fact that it breaks things).

Comment: hey, thanks for the response and the comment on yesterday's question helped me a lot.  do you think you could provide an example of using powershell_out?  I'm not really sure where to begin

Comment: It works like `shell_out` except the string you give is run using powershell instead of cmd.exe or being run directly.